# Can't visualize the insertion of a node at the end of a linked list

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm currently trying to understand and visualize the linked lists in Java.

I understand the basic concept of linked lists and how nodes are added at the head of the list. However, I do not understand how the new node is added at the end of the linked list.

For instance, in the following code:

```java
public class LinkedList
{
    Node head; // head of list

    /* Linked list Node*/
    class Node
    {
        int data;
        Node next;
        Node(int d) {data = d; next = null; }
    }

    public void append(int new_data)
    {
        /* 1. Allocate the Node &
        2. Put in the data
        3. Set next as null */
        Node new_node = new Node(new_data);

        /* 4. If the Linked List is empty, then make the
            new node as head */
        if (head == null)
        {
            head = new Node(new_data);
            return;
        }

        /* 5. This new node is going to be the last node, so
            make next of it as null */
        new_node.next = null;

        /* 6. Else traverse till the last node */
        Node last = head;
        while (last.next != null)
            last = last.next;

        /* 7. Change the next of last node */
        last.next = new_node;
        return;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        /* Start with the empty list */
        LinkedList llist = new LinkedList();

        // Insert 6. So linked list becomes 6->NUllist
        llist.append(6);

        // Insert 4 at the end. So linked list becomes
        // 6->4->NUllist
        llist.append(4);
        llist.printList();
    }

    public void printList()
    {
        Node tnode = head;
        while (tnode != null)
        {
            System.out.print(tnode.data+" ");
            tnode = tnode.next;
        }
    }
}
```

While I can visualize the traversal (`last` reaching the end of `llist`), I don't understand why `last = last.next;` (in `public void append(int new_data)`) links the node to the previous one (why the previous `.next` points toward it).

Thanks for your support!

Comment: Here's a [visualization for linked lists](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/QueueLL.html), hope it helps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The basic linked list is simply starting from the Head node and each node in the list points to the next node in the list. The last node will have its `next` set to `null`, until a new node is added at which point the new node becomes the last node.

So the logic is being done here:

```
/* 6. Else traverse till the last node */
        Node last = head;
        while (last.next != null)
            last = last.next;

        /* 7. Change the next of last node */
        last.next = new_node;
```

It starts from the head, and looks at its `next`. If it is not `null` it means it is still not the actual last node of the list, so it sets the `last` variable to the next one. Until finally it finds the one which has its `next` set to `null`. The `last` variable is only truly the actual last one when the while loop finishes.

Then it just sets the `next` of the `last` node to the new node. The new node already has its `next` set to `null` so the next time the traversal is done it will be the `last` node.

Comment: I understand that ```last``` should be put at the end of the list and I also understand how and why ```last.next``` points towards ```new_node```. What I don't understand is how and why the previous node has a pointer towards ```last```. In the current code, why ```last``` is linked to another element? Shouldn't it be a copy of the node carrying the value of 6 (and so not linked to the previous nodes)? In the following visualization, I don't understand the step 34 > 35 : shorturl.at/amIO5

Comment: `last` is not being put anywhere. It is just a reference to a node that already exists. It is like your finger following the chain of nodes in the list starting from the head (where it says `Node last = head`) and then following through by checking the `next` reference which points to the next node, so moving your finger to the next item in the list. That is what is happening in the while loop. When there is nothing else (the condition in the while loop) you know `last` is pointing to the real end node of the list. So the new_node goes after it. You do it by setting the `last.next` reference.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it helps if you just change the code to something similar which still does the same but gives you another viewpoint. Sometimes a variable's naming is all that confuses you.

For better understanding rename `last` to `current` because you begin at the head and then sequently look at each node until you find a node where `next` points to `null` which indicates the end of the list.

Remember that `.next` itself is a node and `current` is used as an iterator.
You could also write it as a `for`-loop:

```
Node current = head;
for(current; current.next != null; current.next)
//now current refers to the last node since current.next now points to null
current.next = new_node;
//The new end is now new_node - new_node.next points to null
```